# mysql_connect not working in XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

I am  using the below code

```
$con = @mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password);
```

While following code is working fine.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
```

my php version is  5.5.33,what is the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't matter, mysql_* is deprecated, you need to use mysqli_* functions, or PDO.

Comment: @user94 Is there any error , remove @ before mysql_connect and you will get the error . Post error as well . FYI mysql_connect is no longer supported

Comment: removed @ but unfortunately I will not get any error.

Comment: Make sure you have full error reporting enabled: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: The mysql functions don't usually report errors by themselves, you have to check for them explicitly. `$con = mysql_connect(...) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: ya I got this error when removing @ "Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\_inc\_class\Database.php on line 39".but this all code is perfectly working in live.

Comment: did you getting any error? so what is it?

Comment: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\_inc\_class\Database.php on line 39

Comment: Then you need to switch to MySQLi or PDO.  Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score -1):

mysql extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: How does this explain his problem? He says he's using 5.5, so it hasn't been removed yet.

Comment: he should use the mysqli.

Comment: Yes, he should. That would be a fine comment, but it's not an answer to the question.

Answer (score -2):

Permanent Solution:You can install xampp with php 5.4. or 5.3 then put your code there.Definetly you not get any error.

I am facing more issue like syntax error or many so i putted my code in 5.4 oh with xampp 1.0.8.Please try This is not my guessing I am putted my code there and i got not any error.

Because:mysql extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.